# How to toggle sort array data from state when click twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Created multiple functions for sorting by rating, stock, and title on click. What I am trying to do if possible, to "toggle" by instance sort movie titles ASC order and second click DESC. Tried creating a default boolean value `isSorted: false` and based on the click set the isSorted to true and if so, sort from B to A.

I am working with React for 1 month now and would highly appreciate if someone can give me some positive feedback on my code so that i can become even better in React.

My React code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { getMovies } from '../services/fakeMovieService';

class Movies extends Component {
    state = {
        isSorted: false,
        movies: getMovies(),
        isDisabled: true,
    };

    // Display all movies but not the one selected.
    handleDelete = movie => {
        this.setState({
            movies: this.state.movies.filter(m => m._id !== movie._id),
            isDisabled: false,
        });

        console.log(`Movie ${movie.title} deleted.`);
    };

    // Sort all video's by title
    sortByTitle = () => {
        this.setState({
            movies: this.state.movies.sort((a, b) =>
                a.title > b.title ? 1 : -1
            ),
            isDisabled: false,
        });

        console.log('sorted by title');
    };

    // Sort all video's by genre
    sortByGenre = () => {
        this.setState({
            movies: this.state.movies.sort((a, b) =>
                a.genre.name > b.genre.name ? 1 : -1
            ),
            isDisabled: false,
        });
        console.log('sorted by genre.');
    };

    // sort all video's by stock size
    sortByStock = () => {
        this.setState({
            movies: this.state.movies.sort(
                (a, b) => a.numberInStock - b.numberInStock
            ),
            isDisabled: false,
        });

        console.log('sorted by stock size.');
    };

    // Sort all video's by rating score
    sortByRating = () => {
        this.setState({
            movies: this.state.movies.sort(
                (a, b) => a.dailyRentalRate - b.dailyRentalRate
            ),
            isDisabled: false,
        });

        console.log('sorted by rating sore.');
    };

    // Add class to the reset button based on the current filter state.
    resetButtonClass = () => {
        let btnClass = 'btn btn-sm btn-';
        btnClass += this.state.isDisabled ? 'warning' : 'primary';
        return btnClass;
    };

    // Reset the video's filter
    resetFilter = () => {
        this.setState({
            movies: [...getMovies()],
            isDisabled: true,
        });

        console.log('Reset movies database.');
    };

    render() {
        const { length: count } = this.state.movies;

        // Check if there are movies available.
        if (count === 0)
            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <h4>There are no movies in the database.</h4>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={this.resetFilter}
                        className="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                        Reset
                    </button>
                </React.Fragment>
            );

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h5 className="pb-2">Showing {count} in the database.</h5>
                <table className="table table-striped table-dark">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th onClick={this.sortByTitle}>Title</th>
                            <th onClick={this.sortByGenre}>Genre</th>
                            <th onClick={this.sortByStock}>Stock</th>
                            <th onClick={this.sortByRating}>Rate</th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <button
                                    onClick={this.resetFilter}
                                    className={this.resetButtonClass()}
                                    disabled={this.state.isDisabled && true}>
                                    Reset filter
                                </button>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.movies.map(movie => {
                            const {
                                _id,
                                title,
                                genre,
                                numberInStock,
                                dailyRentalRate,
                            } = movie;

                            return (
                                <tr key={_id}>
                                    <th>{title}</th>
                                    <td>{genre.name}</td>
                                    <td>{numberInStock}</td>
                                    <td>{dailyRentalRate}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button
                                            onClick={() =>
                                                this.handleDelete(movie)
                                            }
                                            className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                            Delete
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            );
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Movies;
```

P.S. 
is my code clean and understandable?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Nino

Comment: I would say that one of the ways to improve this code is to DRY sorting methods. One function `sortBy` where you would pass the field and sort by it with a more generic method or a method from a dictionary inside the `sortBy` or importing it from `utils` directory if you prefer to keep one.

Comment: Maybe one example? Would be nice!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

Here idea is based on `sorted` key's value we set the return value of sort function and after that we switch the `sort` key's value

```js
let obj = {
  data: [5,4,3,2,1,0],
  sorted: 'dsc'
}

// let first click  happended

obj.data.sort((a,b)=> obj.sorted === 'asc' ? b-a : a-b)
obj.sorted = obj.sorted === 'asc' ? 'dsc' : 'asc'

console.log(obj.data)

// let second click  happended

obj.data.sort((a,b)=> obj.sorted === 'asc' ? b-a : a-b)
obj.sorted = obj.sorted === 'asc' ? 'dsc' : 'asc'
console.log(obj.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt your `sortByTitle` method to change the value of `isSorted` and then conditionally sort it ascending or descending.

```
sortByTitle = () => {
        let movies = this.state.movies
        let isSorted = !this.state.isSorted

        if (!this.state.isSorted){
            movies = movies.sort((a, b) =>
                a.title > b.title ? 1 : -1
            )
        } else {
            movies = movies.sort((a, b) =>
                a.title > b.title ? -1 : 1 
            )
        }

        this.setState({
            isDisabled: false,
            movies, isSorted
        });

        console.log('sorted by title');
    };
```

Comment: Hey Ian! Thanks! but i have a problem.. that when i switch to another toggle it acts weird.

Comment: Just make sure you flip the `isSorted` back to `false` then once clicking on any of the other sortings.

Answer (score 0):

You should store in state the minimal amount of data possible. You don't need to store movies in state because you can always compute movies from `getMovies`, `isSorted` and `isDisabled`:

```js
function computeMovies(sort, isDisabled) {
   switch(sort) {
       case 'TITLE_ASC':
          return getMovies().sort(....);
       case 'TITLE_DESC':
          return getMovies().sort(....);
       ... more cases here
   }
}

render() {
   const movies = computeMovies(this.state.sort, this.state.isDisabled);

   return ...
}
```

putting sorting logic in a pure function makes it easier to test and reason about.

Apply the same principle to set `sort`:

```
function computeSort(sort) {
   switch(state) {
      case 'TITLE_ASC':
         return 'TITLE_DESC'
     ... more cases here
   }
}
```

```
 sort = (sortProp) => {
    switch(sortProp) {
       case 'TITLE':
         this.setState({
            sort: this.state.sort === 'TITLE_ASC' ? 'TITLE_DESC' : 'TITLE_ASC';
         });
       ... more cases here
    }
 }


 render() {
 <th onClick={ () => this.sort('TITLE')}>Title</th>
```